# Experience of linear regression

Tags: book-recommendation, linear-regression

As part of my work (programmer), I need to learn some linear regression. I have a degree in pure mathematics, but not in statistics. In fact, I have one course in statistics and two or three in probabilities.

That theory will be useful in machine learning. Knowing that we program in Python.

Could anyone be able to give me a good book, an introduction, in linear regression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide more context? I'd like to know 1) what you're using linear regression for - e.g., biostatistics, machine learning, business analytics, etc.; and 2) what is your highest level of math that you're comfortable with?

Comment: @Clarinetist she seems to have stated she has a pure mathematics degree. This opens him up to most textbooks on the subject. But I agree the OP can expand upon why just Regression.

Comment: @Clarinetist Ok, I'll clarify my question. :)

Comment: @SandraRoss Also, since you're working as a programmer... I imagine you're probably limited to either R, Python, or SAS. If you could indicate if you're limited to a particular programming language as well, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best intro book there is for data science methods in general, including linear regression, in Python is probably [Data Science from Scratch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/149190142X) by Joel Grus. This covers simple linear regression, multiple regression, and logistic regression, among other traditional methods, as well as a brief tour of the theory. The only disadvantage to this is that you are literally doing everything from scratch - I have heard that this book does not cover these methods using standard Python libraries, such as `scikit-learn` and `pandas`.

Another recommendation I would make is [Real-World Machine Learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617291927). My recollection is that this one covers machine learning methods using more standardized packages, rather than from scratch. This text isn't as theoretically driven as Grus' text.

If you're looking for something more mathematical focusing on linear regession as its own theory ("general linear models" are what they're called - do *not* confuse this with generalized linear models), I would recommend a traditional intro-Ph.D.-level statistics text, such as [Plane Answers to Complex Questions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441998152). I've gotten to know this text very well since I started the Master's program I'm in, but I'm also aware that Agresti released a [similar text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118730038) very recently, and the original [Linear Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118952839) text by Searle (a classic) has been updated with R and SAS code.

After going through this material on linear models - particularly Searle's text - you will be well-prepared to tackle [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387848576), a take on machine learning from a statistical perspective, a.k.a. "statistical learning." This text covers penalization methods, such as LASSO and Ridge regression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you provide one or more pure linear regression books, i.e., a simple math-book in linear regression without any programming language? :)

Comment: @SandraRoss See edit.

Comment: @Chinny84 Thanks, I've added a text on for that one.

Comment: @SandraRoss I've updated the post with more detail.

Comment: Your answer is pretty complete! :)